# Excess Moderators

Tags: support, moderation, user-accounts, badges, stackexchange

As far as I know, we have three elected moderators: [gandalf3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/599/gandalf3), [iKlsR](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/12/iklsr), and [David](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2217/david). This begs the question, who are [Gabe](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1133/gabe), [Oded](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/37/oded), [Robert Cartaino](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/63/robert-cartaino), and however many others that I've missed? How are they moderators?

It did occur to me that since some of them seem to be big personalities on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), maybe they are moderators on every site? But then shouldn't they have the [image] badge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 490 moderator across all the SE sites. (so you are bound to see a diamond or two.)

Yet only the three BSE mods (gandalf3, iKlsR, and me) and *SE employees* will have diamonds attached to our name on this site.

The three users you linked to are [employees](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) of SE (and have mod+ abilities on every site.)

Oded is a dev at SE.
Robert Cartaino is a community manager (CM). CMs have more power then mods, they over see all the sites and come by when help is needed.
While I personally don't know Gabe, his profile says that he too is a Community Manager.

---

About the badge, no they should not have it. From the description of the badge.

> Served as a pro-tempore moderator for a year or through site graduation.

Which means you were appointed by SE and served as a mod on a beta site.
None of those guys asked about fulfill criteria one. (None of them show up in our [mods list](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).) While they have mod abilities, they were not appointed as BSE mods. (Now if SE had appointed one of there own employees as a pro temp mod on BSE, then they would have the badge here.)

Comment: Also, [kudos to mod -1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile)

Comment: @iKlsR Francesca doesn't count as she is a bot. (no offense Francesca)

Comment: When was this Francesca coined?

Comment: links in my question [here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/989/2217) (to answer your question August 2009)

Comment: How come they are called mods when they could easily implement another title such as "Employee" or something similar?

Comment: @Lukaash Good question! There are lots of discussions about this on the main meta, including many feature requests to have them differentiated. I think [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79276/278094) sums up quite well why SE wont have a different category for employees.